# Checking if an email exist

Tags: grails, groovy

My Model contains the following:

```
String username
```

In the `UserController.groovy` i have a method called `checkIfEmailExist`. When the user types an email address it takes it and goes and checks if that email is available.

```
def checkIfEmailExist() {

if(User.get(params.username)!=null && User.get(params.username).username==email){

println "FOUND EMAIL"



} else {

println "NOT FOUND EMAIL"

}


}
```

The code crashes. and i think there's an error  in

`User.get(params.username)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is for lookups by ID, if you want to look up a domain object based on other properties then you need a `findBy` dynamic finder

```
def user = User.findByUsername(params.username)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to know if a user with this email address exists, I'd do it like this

```
if (User.countByUsername(params.username)) {
  println "FOUND EMAIL"
} else {
  println "NOT FOUND EMAIL"
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `User.findByUsername`, but it's less efficient because you're unnecessarily returning a `User` instance.